# Restrict users with regard to their MAC addresses. Is it possible with Squid?

Tags: mac-address, squid

I need to restrict the users with regard to their MAC addresses. Is it possible with Squid?

Comment: thanx @slhck it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Squid FAQ: [Can I set up ACL's based on MAC address rather than IP?](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#Can_I_set_up_ACL.27s_based_on_MAC_address_rather_than_IP.3F)

You first need to compile Squid accordingly:

```
./configure --enable-arp-acl ...
make clean
make
```

… and then – for example – add these lines to `squid.conf`:

```
acl M1 arp 01:02:03:04:05:06
acl M2 arp 11:12:13:14:15:16
http_access allow M1
http_access allow M2
http_access deny all
```

These are only supported on *nix systems. If `src/acl.c` doesn't compile, this means it won't work.